# How to plot time series in seaborn with one day a x label?

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a dataframe which represents a time series of five days with one day 48 rows of data like:

```
   Density Value     start time
       0.328336  2012-01-16 00:00:00
       1.195605  2012-01-16 00:30:00
       2.398546  2012-01-16 01:00:00
       1.320956  2012-01-16 01:30:00
       1.292287  2012-01-16 02:00:00
       1.286741  2012-01-16 02:30:00
       ...
       0.199826  2012-01-20 23:00:00
       0.437794  2012-01-20 23:30:00
```

I tried to use `seaborn` to draw a time series graph with one day only one label on time axis, which means there are only 5 labels (from 2012-01-16 to 2012-01-20) on x-axis. I have tried `seaborn.tsplot` like `sns.tsplot(data=density_list,time=start_time_list)` but only get the axis labels as the following picture shows:
[image]

I am wondering how I can get the x labels I want in this case. Thanks!

Comment: So you want 5 x values and 5 y values?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want the whole y values with only 5 x labels represented by date.

Comment: Can't you hard code your xticks-labels using a standard matplotlib approach? `fig, ax = plt.subplots()` `ax.set_xticklabels(your_desired_labels)`. Are your dates `datetime64` or `datetime`?

Comment: My date type is `datetime64`  and  `set_xticklabels` seems to only label the first five data instead of the whole data.

Comment: `your_desired_labels` should be a list containing your desired labels, but since it looks like you want to label the xticks with a comprehensive datetime format, I'd recommend setting a major formatter, `def format(date,loc): return pd.to_datetime(date)` and then `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpl.ticker.FuncFormatter(format))`, you can read the docs in [here](http://matplotlib.org/2.0.0rc1/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.Formatter). I think this should do the trick, but I can't test it right now. Edit: `mpl` is just matplotlib library.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried both and seems that now it can visualize the date but still there are more than one labels for each day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion from @Vinícius Aguiar, I followed the answer in [Possible duplicate of Seaborn tsplot does not show datetimes on x axis well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255815/seaborn-tsplot-does-not-show-datetimes-on-x-axis-well) and modified it to get the labels I want.

When I use `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.AutoDateLocator())`, I get the result like [image] and after I read the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#date-tickers) I tried `mdates.DayLocator(interval=1)` and it works!

[image]