# How to set correct time values to seaborn (tsplot) x-axis

Tags: python, plot, seaborn, ntp

I am working on a script, that reads in a NTP- Log File (loopstats) to make an easy readably plot file to see in one single view, if the Offset, recorded by a NTP Client (e.g. Application Server) meets a certain requirement. In my case, the offset mus be less then 0,001 Seconds from the Time Source (NTP Server).

The plot is done, as well as some further needed convertions, but now I am stuck with the format/shown Values of the x- Axis in seaborn.

Here is the shortened code, as far as i came...

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

Seconds = "600s"
dfOut = pd.DataFrame()

df = pd.read_csv('loopstats.txt', sep='\s', engine='python', 
index_col=False, header=None)
df.columns = ['Date', 'Time', 'Offset', 'Drift', 'Jitter', 'Stability', 
'Poll']
df.index = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'], unit='S')

dfOut['meanOut'] = df.Offset.resample(Seconds).mean()
dfOut['timeOut'] = dfOut.index.values

df['minOffset'] = df['Offset'] - df['Jitter']
df['maxOffset'] = df['Offset'] + df['Jitter']

dfOut['minOut'] = df.minOffset.resample(Seconds).min()
dfOut['maxOut'] = df.maxOffset.resample(Seconds).max()

sns.tsplot(data=[dfOut['meanOut'], dfOut['minOut'], dfOut['maxOut']],\
           value='Offset [in Seconds]',\
           color="blue",\
           time=dfOut['timeOut'])

plt.show()
```

I would like to get the x-axis in nearby every constant step (I tried to get a correct time value every 2 Hours), but reached just these numbers, that indicates to the row in the dataframe or inexplicable values with 1e13 on there end of the x- axis.

Here is a plotted outputs of the script above:
[tsplot with time-parameter set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tIPr.png)

Without the time- parameter set, it's a bit better, but still not, what I need (just code, as I am out of allowed links in my first post):

```
sns.tsplot(data=[dfOut['meanOut'], dfOut['minOut'], dfOut['maxOut']],\
           value='Offset [in Seconds]',\
           color="blue")
```

I retouched this plot to show you exactly, what I mean:

[As it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb4MG.png)

I am grateful for any suggestions and help !!!

Comment: I guess the problem is sufficiently covered in [this duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255815/seaborn-tsplot-does-not-show-datetimes-on-x-axis-well). Since we do not know the data, it might be that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795348/plotting-time-series-data-with-seaborn) is better suited. If both do not help, we need a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your hints, I am on a pretty good way now with matplotlibs. Next time I will provide data as well. In this case it's jsut the loopstats file of an NTPv4 Daemon. But again, Thank you for the hints, I am happy with that!