# Seaborn time axis: show date instead of nanoseconds

Tags: python, date, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe with a date column (`RankingDate`).

This date field is initially a string loaded from a csv in the the format "2006-11-03"

After running `df["RankingDate"]=pd.to_datetime(df["RankingDate"])`, the data type becomes `'<M8[ns]'`

I then plot multiple lines over time using seaborn:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 8))
sns.tsplot(data, time='RankingDate', unit='Dummy', condition='Player', value='Points', ax=ax)
```

However this gives me a chart where the date axis is labelled in nanoseconds (i.e. 1e10^18), instead of a nice date format like "2006-11-03".

How can I get seaborn to display a date instead of nanoseconds?

Example code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
RankingDate = ['2015-03-02','2015-03-03','2015-03-04','2015-03-05','2015-03-06']
Player = ['Player1','Player2','Player2','Player1','Player1']
Points = np.random.randn(5)
df = pd.DataFrame({'RankingDate': RankingDate , 'Player': Player, 'Points': Points})
df["RankingDate"]=pd.to_datetime(df["RankingDate"])
df["Dummy"]=0

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 8))
sns.tsplot(df, time='RankingDate', unit='Dummy', condition='Player', value='Points', ax=ax)
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31262531/3349443).

Comment: I wouldn't rely too much on `tsplot` as it will likely be removed or considerably changed in some future seaborn version - I guess the reason being that it caused a lot of confusion.  Is there any reason to use `tsplot`? Why not use normal line plots? Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795348/plotting-time-series-data-with-seaborn) could be of help?