# convert pandas datetime64[ns] to matplotlib date-float for date x-axis in seaborn tsplot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Ok I'm trying to do something that should be trivial but instead I've spent more time than I'd like to admit searching google and stack overflow only to become more frustrated.

What I'm trying to do: I'd like to format my x-axis on a seaborn tsplot.

What my stack overflow searching has told me: matplot lib has a set_major_formattter function but I can't seem to use it without tripping an overflow error.

What I'm looking for: a simple way to convert datetime64[ns] to a float that can be used with marplot lib's set_major_formatter.

Where I think I'm stuck:

```
df.date_action = df.date_action.values.astype('float')
# converts the field to a float but matplotlib expects seconds since 0001-01-01 not nano seconds since epoch
```

is there a simple way to do this that I'm missing?

the most helpful post I reviewed so far was
[31255815](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255815/seaborn-tsplot-does-not-show-datetimes-on-x-axis-well/38332365) which got me 95% of the way there but not quite

here is some sample code to illustrate the issue

```
# standard imports
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()

## generate fake data
from datetime import timedelta, date
import random

def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_date = date(2013, 1, 1)
end_date = date(2018, 6, 2)

date_list = []
number_list = []
for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
    date_list.append(single_date)
    if len(number_list) > 0:
      number_list.append(random.random() + number_list[-1])
    else:
      number_list.append(random.random())

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date_action': date_list, 'values': number_list})
# note my actual data comes in as a datetime64[ns]
df['date_action'] = df['date_action'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
# the following looked promising but is still offset an incorrect amount
#df.date_action = df.date_action.values.astype('float')
#df.date_action = df.date_action.to_datetime

## chart stuff
plt.clf()

import matplotlib.dates as mdates
df['dummy_01'] = 0

rows = 1
cols = 1
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=rows, ncols=cols, figsize=(10, 8))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((rows, cols), (0, 0))

for i in [ax1]: # trying to format x-axis
  pass
  i.xaxis_date()
  i.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.AutoDateLocator())
  i.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m'))

sns.tsplot(df, time='date_action', unit='dummy_01',
           value='values', ax=ax1) #
plt.plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you sure you need a `tsplot` here?

Comment: I don't need tsplot. lineplot looks like it will be much better but that hasn't been released in a stable version yet.

https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/pull/1285

Comment: `lineplot` is available in the newest seaborn version.

Comment: Looks like it was [released](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/releases/tag/v0.9.0) on July 16th. 4 days after this question was asked, cool stuff!